# Select box Border Radius not working in IE6

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6, cross-browser, drop-down-menu

I have a website and i need to implement border radius for text box and Selet box.
Text-boxes are working fine on IE6 with the Support of HTC File.

But Unfortunately Select box not working. its taking the default value.

Check out this link:
http://i40.tinypic.com/qyzs0p.jpg

Please Help me to fix this issues.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This is something you can't really do anything about. You're lucky to have a .htc script working for IE6 for most elements.

Comment: Let IE6 _die_. 7.9% of the world use it. You can safely ignore it. http://www.ie6countdown.com/

Comment: Here is a quick fix: `<!--[if IE 6]> *{display:none}  <! [endif] -->`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is not possible to achive what you are looking for. The level of customization allowed using CSS styles applied to dropdown elements is very basic as far as I know, even more in old-IEs.

If you really need that border, check for dropdown replacement plugins such as : 
http://v2.easy-designs.net/articles/replaceSelect/

However Im not fully sure about its compatibility with IE6.

If I were you, I wouldnt bother too much with IE6 styles... it is really and old browser, the web must go on. As far as you app is working fine, a border is not a big deal.

Good luck! :-)